# Changing Img src. Only one image updates

Tags: jquery, html, image

I am trying to change the image src that match the condition. It is changing the src properly for the first of two images on the page. Can anyone explain why the second image is not changing? Thanks.

html:

```
<div class="columns large-4 extraImageVer2">
    <img src="?Action=thumbnail&amp;Width=600&amp;algorithm=fill_proportional" />
</div>
<div class="columns large-4 extraImageVer2">
    <img src="?Action=thumbnail&amp;Width=600&amp;algorithm=fill_proportional" />
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".extraImageVer2 img").each(function() {
    var imgValue = $(".extraImageVer2").find("img").attr("src");
    if (imgValue === "?Action=thumbnail&Width=600&algorithm=fill_proportional") {
        $(this).attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/600x300');
    }
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phorden/9wz4rnwf/

Comment: That's because you're always selecting the first image inside the "each" block. Use "this".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your imgValue value is incorrect. `.find()` searches descendants. You already selected the image, so you need this:

```
var imgValue = $(this).attr("src");
```

instead of what you have now:

```
var imgValue = $(".extraImageVer2").find("img").attr("src");
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9wz4rnwf/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9wz4rnwf/5/)

```
$(".extraImageVer2 img").each(function() {
    var imgValue = $(this).attr("src");
    if (imgValue === "?Action=thumbnail&Width=600&algorithm=fill_proportional") {
        $(this).attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/600x300');
    }
});
```